# How to convert Arc/Info binary grid file to GeoTIFF in Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have the following Arc/Info binary grid file directory. How can I convert it into GeoTIFF using Python?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python and the GDAL library to convert an ESRI arc/info GRID to a GeoTiff.

```
import gdal
#Your arc/info grid file master folder....
inras = '/home/gbg/Python/test/whatcodtm'
#The path and name to your output tif
outras = '/home/gbg/Python/test/foo.tif'
ds = gdal.Translate(outras, inras)
```

This assumes you have [GDAL installed](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) to your Python environment.

You can add a number of options to your translation.  [See gdal.Translate here](https://gdal.org/python/).  For more help on using translate options in Python you should create a new focused question and show what code you have.

In the example above I point to the top directory that contains the GRID files.  You can also point to the *.adf files inside that top directory [as described here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/aig.html).

The above example was coded on Linux.  The code below failed on a Windows 10 computer with the Python interpreter pointed at an ESRI ArcGIS Pro v2.9 Python installation with a null pointer exception. I do not know why that failed.

```
from osgeo import gdal
#Your arc/info grid file master folder....
inras = r'C:\test\whatcodtm'
#The path and name to your output tif
outras = r'C:\test\foo.tif'
ds = gdal.Translate(outras, inras)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I receive a null pointer error when I apply this. 

ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.

Comment: Are you using Python via ArcGIS Pro?  Maybe ESRI disabled the AIG driver with their GDAL installation?

Comment: No, I am using it directly in python with GDAL. I will see AIG driver then